# custom date (in range)selection calendar in Objective c or Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, calendar

I want to make calendar like attached image.I have searched it my best but i didn't get similar kind of calendar in which i can do change as per my requirement.so please can anyone help me with. [image: calendar image]

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/Glow-Inc/GLCalendarView

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dslcalendarview

Comment: So build a custom control.

Comment: When you say you searched, what search term did you search for? Have you checked out cocoa pods?

Comment: did u found a solution? I also need custom date picker

Comment: Yup you can customize   
 this (https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/) .It's a good library use this and customize it according to your need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution #1**

Have you tried -> [This one](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar)?

Here are some screen shots of the kinds of calendars it can make -> https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/issues/2

It can definitely make yours very easily.
Here is an image of one that is very similar to yours -> [on this GitHub link](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/issues/97)

According to the developer, the library can make **literally any** grid style calendar, and the design is entirely up to you.

**Solution #2**

You can take the difficult road and build the thing your self.
Here is an excellent site which instructs you on how to build one -> [Here](http://blog.karmadust.com/lets-create-a-calendar-using-a-uicollectionview/).
It will take a while to build.